# CAST AS BINARY in ORDER BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Reviewing some legacy code, I found a query which seems to be, at best, poorly written.  Is there some theoretical (performance?) advantage to writing the `ORDER BY` in that manner?  After all, SQL Server defaults to not caring about case.

```
SELECT PreferredName
FROM NameList
ORDER BY CAST(LOWER(PreferredName) AS BINARY)
```

It likely doesn't matter for this question, but the `PreferredName` column is defined as NVarchar(1000).

Comment: Then it's probably affecting the _behavior_ more than the _performance_.  The odd thing is that it's converting to lower case _before_ binary, so I could not tell you what the purpose would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope.

Would agree that's badly written.

The `LOWER` and `CAST` functions prevent any index being used to avoid a sort.

Additionally the cast to binary means many characters will not be sorted in their correct place per usual Unicode string sorting rules.

Also the cast to binary without any length specified will truncate names longer than 15 characters (30 bytes).

Comment: @cdc it could read the values from the index but would still have to sort them. Hence "to avoid a sort" in my answer.

Comment: The collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.  Does that make the changes in the sort order predictable?  There are unfortunately no comments in the code to explain the intent.

Comment: @thatblair Casting to binary means it is just ordered as bytes. It doesn't use any collation rules at all so the collation isn't relevant.

Comment: That was silly. I was thinking the collation would influence what the specific set of characters was, but that's dictated by unicode.  When you say "...many characters will not be sorted in their correct place...," what do you mean?  I can see where "A short phrase 1" may sort unexpectedly vs "A short phrase 2" (both are 17 characters), but is there something akin to "The letter 'B' might appear before 'A'"?

Comment: Answering my own question with a few more years of acquired knowledge -- some Unicode characters require more than one byte.  So `B` would still occur after `A`, however multibyte characters could be sorted in ways other than their collating orders.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't see how there could possibly be an advantage.

The issue here is that the ORDER BY can't use an indexed column. If you add an index on PreferredName and get rid of the CAST and LOWER, I bet you'd see large improvement on large datasets.

Comment: We don't know if the lower changes the query unless we know the collation of the database.  If it is case sensitive, it will change the sort.

Comment: @CDC you're right. I misread and thought it was casting to a BIT

Comment: Collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, so no, not case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I could see for doing it that way is if I wanted to sort the first N characters.  Doing a lower and then casting to binary doesn't provide any benefit that I can see.  That being said, the default length of cast is 30 per documentation ([BOL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)), so it will only order on the first 30 binary bits.  Perhaps that saves some time when doing the sort hashing?